# Matsubara sum arising from QFT and contour integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration, quantum-field-theory

In the [lecture](http://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter5-edited.pdf) of E. Fradkin on quantum field theory, an example of [Matsubara sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency) is performed using contour integration (see eq. 5.214 in the lecture). It reads
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+x^2}
= \oint_{C_{+}\cup C_{-}} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{iz\tau}}{z^2+x^2} \pi\cot(\pi z)\quad(\tau, x>0),
$$
where $C_{\pm}$ denotes the lines $z\pm i\epsilon$ followed counter clockwise (see this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FukSK.png)). I see that above equation can be deduced applying residue theorem to the finite box, obtained by truncating $C_{+}\cup C_{-}$, and taking a limit.

To evaluate the right hand side, the author deforms the contour into $C^{+}\cup C^{-}$ and calculate instead residues at $z=\pm ix$. I am curious about the mathematical justification of this process.

To me, equating $\oint_{C_{-}}(\text{integrand})$ with residue at $-ix$ seems illegitimate since $e^{iz\tau}$ blows up as $z\rightarrow -i\infty$. I don't get what 'deforming $C_{-}$ to $C^{-}$' even means.

One approach that I tried is the change of variable $z\rightarrow 1/z$, which amounts to passing to the other coordinate chart of Riemann sphere. It goes like
$$
(RHS)=\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{i\tau/z}}{1+z^2x^2} \pi\cot(\pi/z),
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the image of $C_{+}\cup C_{-}$ followed counter clockwise. The problem here is twofold; first, $\Gamma$ passes through the essential singularity at $z=0$. Second, if $C_{+}\cup C_{-}$ is taken to be the limit of boxes $B_n$ and $\Gamma$ the limit of their images $B'_n$, each contour $B'_n$ encircles an infinite subset of the poles $\{\pm 1/n: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. I have no idea if I can apply the residue theorem and take a limit in this case.

### edit

Following Svyatoslav's suggestion, I obtained (for $0<\tau<2\pi$)
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+x^2}
= \oint_{C_{+}\cup C_{-}} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{iz\tau}}{z^2+x^2} \frac{\pi e^{-i\pi z}}{\sin\pi z}
= \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{\cosh(\pi-\tau)x}{\sinh(\pi x)} \\
= \frac{\pi}{x} \left[ \cosh(\tau x) \coth(\pi x) - \sinh(\tau x) \right].
$$
However, it is claimed in (5.215) of the lecture that
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+x^2}
\approx \frac{\pi}{2x}\coth(\pi x) e^{-|\tau|x} \quad \text{for small } \tau.
$$
Did the author make a mistake?

Comment: You are right - $e^{iz\tau}$ blows up at $z\to-i\infty$ if we use $\pi\cot(\pi/z)$. It is more convenient here to use $\pi\frac{e^{-\pi{i}z}}{\sin(\pi{z})}$ instead of $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ (which also has the residual $=1$ at integer $z$), if the contour goes below and above axis $X$ counter clockwise. The condition $r\in(-\pi;\pi)$ provides convergence at $z\to\pm{i}\infty$

Comment: could you elaborate on what $r$ is and how your modification deals with both limits $z\rightarrow\pm i\infty$?

Comment: Sorry for mistake - I designate $r$ your $\tau$, and $r\in(0;2\pi)$ At $z=-it$ ($t$ - a real positive number) and $t\to\infty$ we get $e^{izr}\frac{e^{-\pi{i}z}}{\sin(\pi{z})}$$\sim\frac{\exp(-(\pi-r)t)}{exp(\pi{t})}=\exp(-(2\pi-r)t)\to0$. If $z=it$ and $t\to+\infty$ $e^{izr}$$\frac{e^{-\pi{i}z}}{\sin(\pi{z})}\sim\frac{\exp(-(r-\pi)t)}{exp(\pi{t})}=\exp(-rt)\to0$.

Comment: As soon as $r>2\pi$ or $r<-0$ due to periodicity of $\exp(inr)$ the value of the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inr}}{n^2+x^2}$ reduces to the case $r\in(0;2\pi)$. For example $\exp(-\pi{i}n/2)=\exp(3\pi{i}n/2)$, so the case $r=-\pi/2$ is identical to $r=3\pi/2$

Comment: To get a closed form of the sum you should then deform the contour to the big circle $R\to\infty$, "catching" the poles at $z=\pm{i}x$

Comment: If you need further help please let know.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I appreciate your help. In the question, I wrote down what I found out following your suggestion. My result seems inconsistent with the author's, so please check if you can. Further, if you register an official answer I will accept it.

Comment: I checked your calculation - the result is correct. You can also make  another check putting $\tau=0$. The result is known - $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{x}\coth(\pi{x})$. You can check by direct calculations with the function  $\pi\coth(\pi{x})$ or look in at I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik 1.421 (5). Please pay attention that summation in the book is from $n=1$ to $\infty$

Comment: It is also strange the the author keeps $e^{-\tau|x|}$ though at small $\tau$ this is $1-\tau|x|+...$. But this is another story. Your result is correct :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav, Thank you very much. I compilated and posted your comments as an answer. Of course, if you are to give an official answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: No worry - you did all calculations correctly yourself. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of what I wrote on Physics Stack exchange. I hope this is OK because there is a separate readership here.

You can also derive @Svyatoslav's correct expression   by Poisson Summation:
$$
 \frac 1{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+M^2}=
   \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty   \frac 1{2|M |} e^{-|M||\tau+2\pi n|}, \quad \hbox{(Poisson Summation)}\\
   =  \frac 1 {2M} \frac{\cosh(\pi -\tau)M}{\sinh \pi M}, \quad 0<\tau<2\pi,\nonumber
$$
The first line come from applying Poisson summation to the zero temperature expression
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ik\tau}} {k^2+M^2}=\frac 1 {2|M|}e^{-|\tau||M|} 
$$
and has the  physical interpretation as  the method-of-images sum over the  $n$-fold winding of the particle trajectory around the periodic imaginary time direction.
The passage from the first  to second  lines is just summing  the two  geometric series from  $n=0$ to $ \infty$ and $n=-\infty$ to $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is [@Svyatoslav](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/869237/svyatoslav)'s answer.

That the integrand blows up on the lower half-plane is correct. For a legitimate calculation, put $\pi e^{-i\pi z}$ instead of $\pi\cot(\pi z)$:

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+x^2}
= \oint_{C_{+}\cup C_{-}} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{iz\tau}}{z^2+x^2} \frac{\pi e^{-i\pi z}}{\sin\pi z}
= \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{\cosh(\pi-\tau)x}{\sinh(\pi x)} \\
= \frac{\pi}{x} \left[ \cosh(\tau x) \coth(\pi x) - \sinh(\tau x) \right].
$$

Here we assume, without loss of generality, $0\leq \tau<2\pi$. Note that as $t\rightarrow\infty,$

$$
e^{iz\tau}\frac{\pi e^{-i\pi z}}{\sin \pi z} \sim
\begin{cases}
e^{-\tau t},  &\quad z=it \\ e^{(\tau-2\pi)t}, &\quad z=-it
\end{cases}
$$

so we can close the contour around a large circle toward both the upper and lower half-planes.